# Погода в на питоне

Tags: python, geocoding, weather, pyowm

мне нужно чтобы код по определению погоды показывал погоду по координатам выдаваемым модулем geocoder. Вот код:

```
  import geocoder
  import pyowm
  g=geocoder.ip('me')
  owm=pyowm.OWM('api key')
  observation=owm.weather_at_coords(g.latlng)
  w=observation.get_weather()
  temp=w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
  w.get_detailed_status()
  print(w)
  print(temp)
```

ссылка

Comment: https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/

не помогает?

Comment: Вам ошибку даже подсветка кода показывает) Не закрыли строку.

Comment: nomnoms12 это просто косяк когда код переписывал сюда. ОШибка в другом. ПРи попытке запуска кода мне выдают сообщение о том что в строке observation=weather_at_coords(g.latlng) не достаточно аргументов. Если я пишу так observation=weather_at_coords(g.latlng, g.latlng) то пишет 'value must be a number'

Answer (score 0):

`g.latlng` — это список вида `[x, y]`. А метод `weather_at_coords` принимает две отдельные координаты. Распакуйте список.

***Пример***

```py
obs = owm.weather_at_coords(*g.latlng)
```

Comment: ошибка исправлена но другая ошибка "удаленный хост принудительно разорвал соединение" что делать с этим?вот:Traceback (most recent call last):

urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))

Comment: @Деррил Данная ошибка связана с интернет-соединением. Сказать точнее без дополнительной информации не могу. Приведите её, пожалуйста, в вопрос.

Comment: вот поправил как то так там чать только но сама ошибка на 5000 букв

Comment: и что вы там писали про бесплатный план подписки?

Comment: @Деррил Ошибка связана с интернет соединением. Что-то блокирует запрос (файервол, провайдер и т. д.). Сказать точнее не могу. Попробуйте использовать `proxy`. По поводу подписки, я ошибся, убрал из вопроса постскриптум.

Comment: что длеать с прокси?

Comment: @Деррил Для начала скажите, где Вы запускаете скрипт? На том же ПК, с которого задаёте вопрос? У Вас могут быть проблемы с интернетом и конкретно с доступом к OpenWeatherMap API?

Comment: это относиться к моему api ключу ' pyowm.exceptions.api_call_error.APIInvalidSSLCertificateError: Exception in calling OWM Weather API'. да скрипт запускаю через pycharm на том же ПК откуда пишу

Comment: @Деррил Файервол какой-нибудь есть? От антивируса, например. Если есть, попробуйте отключить и попробовать ещё раз. Если нет, то я больше не знаю, чем Вам помочь. Ошибка точно связана с тем, что не удаётся подключиться к OpenWeatherMap API. Причин может быть много.

Comment: файерволов нету антивирус не работает может проблема в том что я создал 3 api ключа и они не работают

Comment: @Деррил Я проверил этот код, использовав первый же ключ API, который мне выдали после регистрации. Но работать он начал только спустя минут 10-15. Поначалу выдавал ошибку о том, что у меня не хватает прав.

Comment: ключам уже неделя

Comment: один был создан сегодня

Comment: код я изменил и ошибок стало меньше но ошибка с хостом ещё есть

Comment: @Деррил Пожалуйста, приведите полную ошибку в вопрос, несмотря на то, что она очень длинная. Потому что по отрывкам строк ошибки помочь Вам очень сложно. Если не я, то кто-то другой увидит и, возможно, ответит Вам.

Comment: ошибка не умещается может у вас есть почта или соцсети куда можно отослать полную ошибку?

Comment: @Деррил Залейте на https://pastebin.com/ и добавьте в вопрос ссылку.

Comment: вот ссылка на пастебин https://pastebin.com/gn96AQd1

Comment: вот https://pastebin.com/gn96AQd1